# How to load an image in a Java console application? (without an applet)

Tags: java, awt

I'm making a Java console application that outputs a series of image files, and I want to draw an image file as part of the output. getImage doesn't seem to work though, it needs Toolkit or something.

```
Image cover = getImage("cover.png");
```

Any ideas?

Edit: The program doesn't display images, it generates them and saves them into a series of files. I figured out how to save the images, and drawing basic geometry works, but not images for whatever reason.

Comment: You want to draw an image in the console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way of working with different image-formats is the ImageIO class. The following example converts a jpg into png and draws a cross.

```
public class ImageReaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     try{
          BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/tmp/input.jpg"));

          image.getGraphics().drawLine(1, 1, image.getWidth()-1, image.getHeight()-1);
          image.getGraphics().drawLine(1, image.getHeight()-1, image.getWidth()-1, 1);

          ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/tmp/output.png"));
     }
     catch (IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that, I was using ImageIO to write the image!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not actually trying to draw the image, but just trying to use the awt classes, you need to tell awt to run in headless mode by setting the `java.awt.headless` system property.  You can either do this in your program, before awt gets loaded:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

or by setting the property on the command line when you run your program:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true Program
```

Comment: So do I make my program an applet and just set that to make it not display anything?

Comment: @nkorth Are you actually wanting to display the image? I was never clear on that.  If not, you don't have to make it an applet.  Setting the headless property lets you use classes from the AWT api without without requiring the display.

Comment: No, I don't need to display the image. I was wondering whether I need to structure my program as an applet (with `init()`, `paint()`, etc.), because I would really prefer just using a simple `main()` structure.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to draw it ? Seeing it that you need some output this could help, assuming bmps( but other formats are explained):

http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/Encode.doc.html

```
 // Define the source and destination file names.
 String inputFile = /images/FarmHouse.tif
 String outputFile = /images/FarmHouse.bmp

 // Load the input image.
 RenderedOp src = JAI.create("fileload", inputFile);

 // Encode the file as a BMP image.
 FileOutputStream stream =
     new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
 JAI.create("encode", src, stream, BMP, null);

 // Store the image in the BMP format.
 JAI.create("filestore", src, outputFile, BMP, null);
```

Reads and writes a Bmp File.

Comment: I probably should have clarified that I already figured out how to output image files (PNG actually). Thanks anyway!